# gem error on remote machine

Tags: ruby, rubygems, google-client

I made a dashing app that queries the google api as part of its jobs. On my local everything works fine and I used git to clone the repo on a remote machine and ran `bundle install` there but when I try to run `dashing start` I get this error:

```
/home/mwerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/signet-0.5.1/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:941:in `fetch_access_token': Authorization failed.  Server message: (Signet::AuthorizationError)
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
```

I am using relative paths in the app so it can't be there is an authentication issue. I tried manually installing all the gems I use on the local machine on the remote machine via `gem install ...` but no luck. Hints?

Comment: where is the auth token stored? environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue today. I got it resolved by checking back into my google developers account. In my case I had entered a wrong Mail address under `service_account_email` in the `.rb` file. 
I inserted the data shown under "Client ID for Web Apps" where it had to be the one from "Service Account" out of my Google Developer API Account. Make sure you use `Service Account` Credentials for the widget! 
Also I reassured that I had setup that very same address for read access in my google analytics account.
In short, getting that error means there is something wrong with the data you put in the `analytics.rb` file.

Once I did the above it resolved my issue and I was able to start dashing.